# how to focus on an input when a key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I'm making this acres and karats calculator thing for my uncle, I'm using vanilla javascript, and I want to get focus on text input and type that number in the text box when I press any of the numpad keys on the keyboard, I've been searching online for like an hour but I couldn't find what I wanted.
[image: an Image of the calculator]

So this is what it looks like. 
Oh, I also forgot to mention that I want to make the clicking animation happen when I press a key on the keyboard but I have no idea how to do that.
Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

`

```
function onekey(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 1) {
        input.focus();
        input.value += 1;
    }
 }
```

`

`<td><button id="one" onkeypress="onekey(event)">1</button></td>`

Comment: Your going to need to post your code before we can help you.

Comment: it looks pretty good. But as @SmokeyDawson mentioned kinda hard to help without some code,

Comment: @SmokeyDawson oh sorry I completely forgot

Comment: @SmokeyDawson I added the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically your issue is your listening for a keypress on your number buttons - you need to create a global keypress listener that will listen for any keypress and then update your input

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

function listenForKeyPress() {
  // add document event listener for all key presses
  document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    // check to see if the keypress was a number
    if (/[0-9]/g.test(e.key)) {
      // check to see if the input is not already focused
      if (document.activeElement !== input) {
        // focus element
        input.focus();
        // focus value
        input.value += e.key;
      }
    }
  })
}

// call function
listenForKeyPress();
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" />
```

So as you can see we are

1. Listening for any keypress
2. Checking to see if the keypress was a number between 0 - 9 using regex
3. Checking to see if the input is already focused
4. If the input is not already focused - focus the input and update the input value

another issue you probably will have now is that clicking on your element doesnt update the input value so you can do this

```js
function key(event) {
  // get input
  const input = document.getElementById('input');
  // focus input
  input.focus();
  // update the value with the innerText of the clicked element - which is the number 1
  input.value += event.toElement.innerText;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" />
<button id="one" onclick="key(event)">1</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working now, but clicking on the element works anyway cause I've  already added event listener when I click the button

Comment: There's one more thing I want the clicking animation to work when I press the numbers on the keyboard, could I add this using a class in css and use classList.toggle in my javascript, it would be great if you can help me with that